# 404 error when resolving project to server. how to fix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, custom-error-pages

Everything seems to be fine with the project, everything is fine in dev mods, even on hosting everything is fine, but there is a need to run the project on the webos emulator and it already gives a 404 error. Such a strange thing can work as it should, I'm not sure. If you pull out the build folder from its native directory and run serve -s build through the terminal, then again an error 404 comes out. Knowledgeable people help.

I also wanted to add that I changed the versions of the react packages, maybe this is the problem. Weaving versions

```js
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/*' element={<MainPage updateDataParent={updateDataParent}/>} />
      <Route path='/ChanelPage' element={<ChanelPage id={id} chanelData={chanelData} />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>
</Router>

"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hls-player": "^3.0.7",
    "react-player": "^2.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Comment: Please show entire error message

Comment: localhost/:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)